# Brightness driver not working (show different yellow icon)

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, 32-bit

My driver is intel HD Graphics Driver 9.17.10.3347 for Windows 10 32-bit

system shows everything is fine

[image]

But on device manager I am getting  wiered yellow icon (not exclamation mark)

[image]

I am also not able to get this driver anywhere on intel site

"intel HD Graphics Driver 9.17.10.3347 for Windows 10 32-bit"

please let me know the right link for downloading this software for 32 bit , not 64 bit please

thanks

Answer (score 0):

9.17.10.4229 is the last driver made for that chipset, released 6/5/2015.
There are no Windows 10 drivers for it, it was abandoned by Intel.

As there are, & will never be, any current drivers, the chances of everything continuing to work as expected become smaller with each Windows 10 incremental update.

You could try a reinstall, but I'm not sure it will achieve anything.
Download link - https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/24970/Intel-HD-Graphics-Driver-for-Windows-7-8-8-1-32bit?product=81500